# Display Chrome full history

Tags: google-chrome, history

How do I display all of my browsing history in Google Chrome?

When I press Ctrl+H I get most of the visited pages, but there are few missing as shown on following screenshot:
[image: The vertical bar is hiding 20 minutes of my browsing]

Is there a way to get to the 20 minutes replaced by vertical bar?

I'm using Chrome Version 23.0.1271.95.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot directly, as Chrome has paginated history now.

However, if you install the extension [History 2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-2/cahejgbbfgmlmjgdjlibphdjeldhagkp) from the Chrome Web Store, you can view the entire history by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and selecting **All history**.

Comment: Also see [Better History](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-history/obciceimmggglbmelaidpjlmodcebijb) and [History Calendar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-calendar/ilfjhacjjbcdmimjeaakpnlhdcloijcg).

Comment: @WorK will it also show history from all connected devices (by syncing them ? )

Comment: +1 for the history calendar - gave me the best print out.

Comment: @WorK, Hmm, they store the data in MySQL lite right? Then wouldn't we be able to access it directly?

Comment: links to extensions are broken

Answer (score 4):

As the above extension links are broken, here are a few that are currently working:

- [Better History](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-history/egehpkpgpgooebopjihjmnpejnjafefi) (by a different author, the original plugin with the same name [became riddled with ads](https://www.enigmasoftware.com/better-history-chrome-extension-hijacking-browser-ads/))
- [Enhanced History](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enhanced-history/blpnkmdkoapbdhpmemnaikpbhajknmdb) (fork of original Better History plugin, [open-source without "hijacks")](https://github.com/chrome-enhanced-history/enhanced-history)

Answer (score 0):

To show the full history of your Google searches from all connected devices (for searching via Google when you are signed in to a Google account on your browser), you can go to https://history.google.com.

See also the discussion in https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29288/how-to-synchronize-chrome-web-history-on-different-android-devices.

PS I posted this answer because initially I thought that https://history.google.com would display *Chrome browsing history*, but I later realised that this only shows *Google search history* (including searches on browsers other than Chrome). If you browsed anything else on Chrome than via Google searches, this will not show up here. Sorry for the noise, anyway I thought it was more useful to leave this edited answer than to delete it completely.

Comment: Nah. Just delete it completely.

Comment: You can try https://myactivity.google.com/page?page=chrome.